# How to assign fixed value on if condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm transforming several XML using an XSL stylesheet.

However, in some cases, the field "date" has only the year instead of the full date DD/MM/YYYY.

Here an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
    <oeu>
        <oeu_archive_exist_construct_timespan type="daterange">
            <from>1999</from>
            <to>2001</to>
        </oeu_archive_exist_construct_timespan>
    </oeu>
</objects>
```

By applying the following XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"
                indent="yes"
                encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()"
                  mode="copy-no-namespaces">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"
                                 mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="pr:objects/pr:oeu">
        <entry>
            <xsl:element name="construction_time_span">
                <oeu_nc_construction_time_span_from>
                    <xsl:value-of select="pr:oeu_archive_exist_construct_timespan/pr:from"/>
                </oeu_nc_construction_time_span_from>
                <oeu_nc_construction_time_span_to>
                    <xsl:value-of select="pr:oeu_archive_exist_construct_timespan/pr:to"/>
                </oeu_nc_construction_time_span_to>
            </xsl:element>
        </entry>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm having the following output (snapshot):

```
<construction_time_span>
   <oeu_nc_construction_time_span_from>1999</oeu_nc_construction_time_span_from>
   <oeu_nc_construction_time_span_to>2001</oeu_nc_construction_time_span_to>
</construction_time_span>
```

In the cases where the date has only the year I would like to assign the fixed value 1/1 as DD/MM.

My desired output would be:

```
<construction_time_span>
   <oeu_nc_construction_time_span_from>1/1/1999</oeu_nc_construction_time_span_from>
   <oeu_nc_construction_time_span_to>1/1/2001</oeu_nc_construction_time_span_to>
</construction_time_span>
```

Suggestions?

Regards,

Comment: Could you please post a sample input that works with your transformation?

Comment: @Sebastien I have just updated the question with a sample input

Comment: I get this when I apply the transformation to you input : Namespace prefix 'pr' has not been declared

Comment: Do a test for `string-length() = 4` or `not(contains(., '/'))`. If true, prepend `"1/1/"`.

Comment: Proper questions should at least have an input sample that match the transformation: there are patterns that use undeclared namespaces in your stylesheet.